# What is it called when a word is used based on an extant definition which no longer actually applies? e.g. "dial" with phones

Tags: terminology, etymology, semantics, language-change, evolution

It was difficult to phrase what I mean in an accurate and precise way here.

This is similar to a fossil word, but fossil words are words which have fallen out of general use except where they are preserved in an expression.  (for example *fro* in the expression *to and fro*)

I'm talking about a word that is still in general use for its prior purpose, is also used for something directly derived from this meaning, but that this derivation no longer makes sense.

Comment: there is an English phrase "just around the bend", hope it counts.

Comment: Could you explain this a little further?

Comment: Not necessarily related to your example, but to try and clarify the question a further: a *metaphor* to something now uncommon wouldn't qualify as such.  So calling a software product a "flagship" wouldn't be an example.  But (stretching here) describing a future battle spaceship in a space-navy (bear with me) as a "flagship" despite the fact that it bears no physical flag *would be* an example.

Comment: I'd give other real examples, but I'm drawing a blank.  In fact, the reason I asked the question in the first place is because I want to find some other examples, but I don't know what to call the category of word/phrase I'm looking for.

Comment: Are these examples of what you're thinking of: to "hang up" a cell phone; the "gear shift" lever on a CVT automobile; US Army Armored "Cavalry"?

Comment: "bend" was once used for real bends on the roads, but now the phrase just indicates general proximity of a location.

Answer (score 5):

That's called the 'generalization / extension / broadening' of meaning: words with concrete meaning (like 'dialing' meaning 'calling by turning the round wheel on the phone') begin to mean more general things (now 'dialing' means 'calling from any kind of phone'). There are many examples of such generalization: *manuscript* once meant only handwritten documents, now it means any authorized copy, both handwritten and printed; *picture* once meant only a painting, now it means any kind of image, even photos; *pipe* used to mean "a musical wind instrument" now it can mean "any hollow oblong cylindrical body"(e. g. *water pipes*); in Russian *стрелять* (from *стрела* 'arrow') used to mean only 'to shoot arrows', now it means shooting from any kind of weapon, even from tanks and with missiles.